# How can I match two concrete classes by a Property that is generated at runtime - WebAPI?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

This is an extension to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552752/how-to-pass-a-composite-array-from-javascript-to-web-api-controller-httppost/29552820#29552820).

I have to pass CorelationID to my API service and match the Department and Employee Records.

The array that I am passing from Javascript is as under

[image]

**EmployeesAPIController.cs**

```
using System.Web.Http;

    namespace EmployeeService
    {
        [RoutePrefix("Employee")]
        public class EmployeesAPIController : ApiController
        {  
            [HttpPost]
            [Route("InsertEmployeeDepartment")]
            public EmployeeDepartment InsertEmployeeAndDepartment(object employeedepartment)
            {
                var empDept =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeDepartment>(employeedepartment.ToString());

                //insert the new department records
               DepartmentRecords = InsertDepartment(empDept.Departments);

                //fill the employee record with the associated Coreration Id

               Here I have to join the Employee and Department Records by the CorelationID

                //insert employee records
               EmployeeRecords = InsertEmployee(empDept.Employees);             
            }

        }
    }
```

**The JS file is as under**

```
var guid = GenerateGuid();           

            //build the employee object
            var Employee = {
                EmployeeId: $scope.EmployeeId,
                EmployeeName: $scope.EmployeeName,
                Age: $scope.Age,
                Salary: $scope.Salary,
                CorrelationID: guid
            };

            //build the department object
            var Department = {
                Deptid: $scope.DepartmentID,
                Deptname: $scope.DepartmentName,
                CorrelationID: guid
            };
```

How can I do it?

The object looks like(an example)

[image]

**Edit**

I am trying with **Expando Object** as under now

**public EmployeeDepartment InsertEmployeeAndDepartment(ExpandoObject employee)**

[image]

How can I get the Employees and Departments arrays from here?

Comment: How departament records looks like? The CorrelationId will change after insert?

Comment: it depends on the insertion type. if success, then correlation will will remain same else it will change.And based on that I need to match the employees   and only those employees that has a matching corelationID will be eligible for a valid insertion

Comment: I put in my answer this query that will take only the employees that match the `CorrelationId`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to use a join on the correlationID to get the employees with a matching correlationID in the department list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var employees = new List<Employee> { new Employee {Name = "MY_NAME1", CorrelationID = "CID1"}, new Employee {Name = "MY_NAME2", CorrelationID = "CID2"}, new Employee {Name = "MY_NAME3", CorrelationID = "CID3"}};
        var depts = new List<Department> { new Department {Name = "DEPT_NAME1", CorrelationID = "CID2"}, new Department {Name = "DEPT_NAME2", CorrelationID = "CID1"}};

        var joined = employees.Join(depts, x => x.CorrelationID, x => x.CorrelationID, (employee, dept) => new {EmployeeName = employee.Name, DepartmentName = dept.Name});

        foreach(var pair in joined){
            Console.WriteLine("EmployeeName: {0}, DepartmentName: {1}", pair.EmployeeName, pair.DepartmentName);
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string CorrelationID {get;set;}
    }

    public class Department
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string CorrelationID {get;set;}
    }

    public class SqlBuilder{

        private static string _baseSql = "select * from customers";

        public static string GetSql(string customerId){
            var final = _baseSql;
            if(customerId != null)
                final += " WHERE custId=@custId";
            return final;
        }
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
> EmployeeName: MY_NAME1, DepartmentName: DEPT_NAME2 
> EmployeeName: MY_NAME2, DepartmentName: DEPT_NAME1
```

Comment: see, Employee does not have CorelationId, neither Department. That has been created on the fly.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot add them to the definition of your object and ignore them the rest of the time? C# doesn't work well with parameters made on the fly. During your serialization, the correlation object will be ignored.

Comment: yes... we need to create the co-relation id in the client side...it cannot be part of the domain model.. we need to match the records based on the corelation id at server side

Comment: There are two solutions I can think of for that then. One is to use Json.Decode(employeeDepartment) which will return a dynamic object which you will be able to create the values from. The other is to create a new domain model that includes CorrelationID for deserialization purposes only.